# Why is rigidBody.velocity not very accurate in my unity2d project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I was trying to make my object change direction when it moves by 1 unit, so i set its rigidbody.velocity to be 0.25, and set a coroutine that changes its direction every 4 seconds. But i noticed that it has some small inaccuracies (such as changing direction when moved by 0.998), which builds up to a lot after running for some time.

Now I know the best way is probably to just directly change transform.position in this case, but could someone tell me why does my previous method have these inaccuracies?

Edit:

To add a bit of context, im trying to replicate a traditional snake game but with smooth movement(in stead of jumping between the grids). It was a bit hard to explain how the direction can only be changed when the snake has reached a whole unit so i just said that the direction is changed every 4 seconds in the original post. Here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SnakeHead : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    private Vector2 currDir;
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        currDir = Snake.Instance.GetDir();
        StartCoroutine(Move());
    }

    IEnumerator Move()
    {
        while (GameManager.gameIsRunning)
        {
            currDir = Snake.Instance.GetDir();
            rigidBody.velocity = currDir * speed;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / speed);
        }
    }
}
```

note that i set speed to be 0.25 in the unity editor window.

im aware that changing transform.position directly is bad practice, but ive watched several tutorials and all of them did that on the snake's movement. Does anyone know if there's a better way?

Comment: _"Why is rigidBody.velocity not very accurate.... **so i set its rigidbody.velocity** to be xxx"_ - there is your problem right there.  _["In most cases **you should not modify** the velocity directly, as this can result in unrealistic behaviour"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)_.  Use forces instead.

Comment: @MickyD I think the problem is not that it's unrealistic, but that it's not perfectly deterministically accurate as it's used here.

Comment: @pixlhero above is the _general rule_ and unless the OP posts some code _"as it's used here"_ is without foundation.

Comment: @MickyD there's enough written here to gather that they use a coroutine, using a coroutine it's not gonna be possible to set the velocity exactly after 4 seconds. That's what I meant by "as it's used here".

Comment: @pixlhero considering the OP is all about "accuracy", you don't want to be setting the `velocity` period.

Comment: there's a difference between "accuracy" and "realism". setting 'velocity' breaks realism, but it will not change the accuracy or lack thereof. So in this particular case this would not fix the problem.

Comment: In fact, *"Now I know the best way is probably to just directly change transform.position in this case"* isn't quite correct either. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to make it such that you change direction **exactly** after 4 seconds. Using `WaitForSeconds(4)` will not wait **exactly** 4 second, instead it will wait at least 4 seconds as correctly mentioned in the comments. It largely depends on how frequently your coroutine is checked by the engine.

As you already mentioned, it would probably be a good idea to do some explicit actions. Either moving it "by hand" (not through the physics simulation), or periodically set the position to a known value.

Comment: What's `passedTime`?

Comment: as written in the "like this" it's an example how it's probably written. The important part is the '>=' which indicates that it's not (and can't made to be) exactly after 4 seconds.

Comment: I did 'yield return WaitForSeconds(4)' in the coroutine to keep track of the time

Comment: Keep in mind that WaitForSeconds is not exact. Its count starts at the end of the frame it was called on, and will end that count at the start of the first frame where the time elapsed is at least the requested amount.

Comment: I read a bit more about code execution of unity and now I understood, thank you very much!